# How to use xev on VirtualBox to catch mouse event

Tags: linux, ubuntu, listener, virtualbox, xorg

I'm trying to create a mouse listener with `xev` on `VirtualBox`.

I know that according to *[x.org](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/mouse5.html)*, I need to configure the mouse identifier in order to have `xev` listening to it.

I figured out that `xorg.conf` needed to be created at `/etc/X11/` and that the default configuration was in `/usr/lib/X11/xconf.d/`

`xev` test window shows the button press event when the mouse button is clicked.

I would like to achieve the same thing with a predefined windows id.

Here's an exemple of my `xorg.conf` at the moment (`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`)

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
        Driver      "vesa"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier  "Default Screen"
        Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
        Device      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier  "Configured Mouse"
        Driver      "vboxmouse"
        #Driver     "evdev"
        Option      "CorePointer"
        #Option     "Device"        "/sys/devices/virtual/input/input2"
        #Option     "Device"        "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection
```

Anyone knows what I'm missing ?

Comment: what happens if you use `xev -id yourwindow`? How do you create `yourwindow`? Why window created by xev is not what you want?

Comment: For my test case, the window is already opened. I get the window id using _xdotool_ and the I use `xev -id XXXXX` to see what is happening over this particular window. Therefore I would like to be able to listen keyboard events as well as mouse event.